# Change react jsx class dynamically without DOM manipulation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, reactjs

I'm using jsx react and want to set a class dynamically while keep another class static so I want something like the below to keep class `type` but have an additional dynamic class `change` change to class `big` or `small` or whatever.

```
<p className="type {change}">{pokeType}</p>
```

Is there a way to do something like this without using `element.setAttribute` or `document.getElementById...className` or jQuery stuff? Or is it only possible to go through this kinda thing with DOM manipulation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have `change` in your component's state:

```
this.setState({ change: 'myClass1'})

// will yield <p className="type myClass1">...</p>
<p className={`type ${this.state.change}`}>{pokeType}</p> 

this.setState({ change: 'myClass2'})

// will yield <p className="type myClass2">...</p>
<p className={`type ${this.state.change}`}>{pokeType}</p>
```